# Are there ropsten ERC20 testnet tokens?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, testnets, ropsten

I am trying to write an application using `web3.js` and I want to integrate some ERC20 functionality. But rather than muddy up the mainnet, I'd like to try things on the Testnet first. I see that https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x722dd3f80bac40c951b51bdd28dd19d435762180#tokentxns is a standard Testnet token. Is there anyway for me to get my hands on some?

Or perhaps another ERC20 compliant testnet token?

Comment: good question, with apparently no answer.  you'd think, this being one of the most common use cases, like ever, that the Ethereum ecosystem would provide a standard solution, but no.  such a s h i t s h o w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that contract https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x722dd3f80bac40c951b51bdd28dd19d435762180#code you need to call the function `showMeTheMoney` with your address and amount of tokens. It should deposit that amount in your address.

```
function showMeTheMoney(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    totalSupply += _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    Transfer(0, _to, _value);
}
```

Comment: Here's a dumb question - how do I run the function?

Comment: You have the contract address and you can get the contract abi from the etherscan page. With that you can create an instance of the contract and call the method `showMeTheMoney()`.

Comment: But how do I call the method?

Comment: In web3 v1.0 it should be 
```
const token = web3.eth.Contract(TokenABI, TokenAddress);
await token.methods.showMeTheMoney(UserAddress, TokenAmount).send({ from: UserAddress, gas: 200000 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that Etherscan has a beta feature tab called Write Contract and it allows to directly interact with the TST smart contract with the use of Metamask.

[image: Etherscan's Beta version of its Write Contract Feature]

Comment: which, of course, doesn't work on the Standard Test Token: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x90f59eacb8a6c40692dc775cea1341839701979f#writeContract -- because nothing in this ecosystem ever just works

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy own ERC20 token contract to the testnet and use that.

Answer (score -1):

Because all Erc20 tokens have same rules, you can create your own ERC20 token. I have published an article to explain it in step by step tutorial. you can find it here:

https://athamidn.medium.com/step-by-step-get-erc20-test-token-faucet-on-ropsten-d20850375f2c

Comment: you'd think someone would have created this facility by now to save everyone the trouble